# re.search string in python

Tags: python, string, search

I want to take screen name out of strings like this:

```
text = (u'675739242841120768', [{u'id': 9207632, u'indices': [3, 15], u'id_str': u'9207632', u'screen_name': u'brainpicker', u'name': u'Maria Popova'}])
```

I'm not getting any results with this code I thought I needed to use:

```
re.search("screen_name': u'(...)', u'name", text)
```

I'm not sure if I am suppose to add something else inside the parenthesis.

Comment: what is your `text` datatype it does not look like a string from what you have shown and why did not it work was there any error

Comment: It is suppose to be a string

Comment: could you `print type(text)`

Comment: @PedroMuñoz: But you missed another part of what Vignesh said: **What's the error are you getting?**

Comment: @VigneshKalai its a tuple

Comment: @PedroMuñoz: If it's a real tuple, then check Avinash's answer.

Comment: The error I was getting is **TypeError: expected string or buffer**

Comment: @PedroMuñoz that explains all you have to give a `string or buffer` as input to re module but you have given `a tuple` so it shows the error. Avinash answer will work for you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the exact index value since the variable text contain combination of tuples, list, dictionaries.

```
>>> text = (u'675739242841120768', [{u'id': 9207632, u'indices': [3, 15], u'id_str': u'9207632', u'screen_name': u'brainpicker', u'name': u'Maria Popova'}])
>>> text[1][0]['screen_name']
u'brainpicker'
```

You can't apply `re.search` directly to list or tuples or dict , it should accept string as last parameter.

Comment: if it's string `re.search(r"'screen_name': u'(\w+)', u'name'", text).group(1)`

Comment: Mate why don't you add your comment into the answer

Comment: @VigneshKalai op said it's a tuple so not necessary.. :-)

Comment: That was it! Thank you for your help @AvinashRaj